# Can you store emails in Sharepoint Workspace 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, email, sharepoint-2010

I am using SHarepoint Workspace 2010.  I was wondering if there was any way to somehow make the workspace (or even the site) work with Outlook and save emails in the document repository?

Comment: kindly elaborate do you want all the mails backed up or you want your new emails to be recieved in document library

Answer (score 2):

If you want to drag and drop email into any SharePoint 2010 library, SharePoint 2010 allows this out-of-the-box by selecting "**Open with Explorer**" from the "**Connect & Export**" section in the Library Tools ribbon in the applicable library. This will open a browser window, into which you may either drag/drop or copy/paste from your outlook window.

This method is exceptionally helpful when you DON'T want to set up the library to receive email.

Comment: Using this method, all the emails have their date-marks reset to today's date.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you have to integrate your outlook with sharepoint.You need to create a list, which will be seen at your outlook as well. Now when you want to send emails you have to save them in the list as well. So your emails will be saved in the sharepoint list.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing it. If you want to share your e-mail with broader audience you can move it to the Outlook public folder.

Comment: Public folders are not supported in 2010 or are frowned upon. Hence the concept of SharePoint and collaboration with this tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list which accepts emails like a discussion and setup an email address for the list in the settings. Then you can go to your Outlook and set up rules to forward emails to the list which fit a certain criteria.

Also, when viewing a list, you should be able to sync with Outlook (Connect to Outlook button) which would allow you to view it in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Colligo Contributor Pro](http://www.colligo.com/products/sharepoint/colligo-contributor-pro/). It's an alternative for the old fashioned Sharepoint Workspace. You can do everything you want:

- add all kind of files to Sharepoint
- sync when you want
- add emails to your Sharepoint and open them later with your mail program
- add Sharepoint libs to your Outlook and sync them

Answer (score 0):

For drag and drop of emails from Outlook to SharePoint we are using [SharePoint Outlook Integration](http://www.sai-innovations.com/sharepoint-outlook-integration.aspx) tool.  PageLight also offers [Save Outlook emails to SharePoint](http://www.sai-innovations.com/sharepoint-outlook-integration.aspx) functionality